# Loop Segmentation Fault

Tags: string, assembly, integer, x86-64, att

This is my code so far.

```
            .data
S:          .string "-149"
Length:     .byte   -1
Result:     .quad 

            .text
            .globl main

main: 
    mov     S,%rdx              #Storage of string, counter, position and result in memory
    mov     Length, %rcx
    mov     Result, %rax
    mov     $10, %r10
    mov     $30, %r13
    mov     $-1, %r9

Loop1:                          #loop string from beginning to end  
    cmp     $0,0(%rdx)          #compare base addresss value with null
    je      Counter_Made        #if null, branch to end loop. 
    add     %r14, Length        #increment length by for each digit thats not null (creates counter for 2nd loop)
    add     $1, %rdx            #increment base by 1 to move onto next digit in string
    jmp     Loop1               #reinitiate loop


Counter_Made: 
    cmp     %r15,Length         #check if length is zero
    je      Output              #End program, output null result
    cmp     %r15,Length(%rdx)   #Determine negativity/positivity of integer
    jl      Negative_counter
    jmp     Positive_loop 

Positive_loop: 
    cmp     %r9,Length          #End of loop check 
    je      Output              #Store result if loop end condition satisfied
    mov     %r10, Length(%rdx)  #Store byte of integer in supplementary register
    sub     %r13,  %r10         #Conversion from 8bitASCII to 2Bit Binary
    imul    %r11, %r10          #Place holder multiplication 
    add     %r10, %rax          #Store cumulative addition in memory
    sub     %r14, Length        #Length decrement 
    jmp     Positive_loop       #reloop

Negative_counter:
    sub     %r14,Length
    jmp     Negative_loop

Negative_loop: 
    cmp     %r9,Length
    je      Negative_Complement 
    mov     %r10, Length(%rdx)  #Store byte of integer in supplementary register
    sub     %r13, %r10          #Conversion from 8bitASCII to 2Bit Binary
    imul    %r10, %r10          #Place holder multiplication 
    add     0(%rdx), %rax       #Store cumulative addition in memory
    sub     %r14, Length
    jmp     Negative_loop

Negative_Complement:
    not     %rdx                #Convert to 2's complement with negation and then + 1
    add     %r14,%rdx
    jmp     Output

Output:
    mov      %rdx, Result 
    ret 
#size mismatch for imul 
#Specific place in memory to put output or no?
```

The code is supposed to convert a character string that represents any signed integer to its 2’s complement value.

I'm receiving a segmentation fault in one of my loops and I've tried multiple different methods here but to no avail - could anyone explain how I should about fixing this segfault? I'm stumped.

Here is the GDB errors

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Loop1 () at data.s:18
18      cmp     $0,0(%rdx)          #compare base addresss value with null
```

This is the second error.

```
Counter_Made () at data.s:28
28      cmp     $0,Length(%rdx)     #Determine negativity/positivity of integer, if <0 value is negative
```

I'm suspecting its the Length(%rdx) method that I'm trying to interpret the loop with. Would it be better to `sub $1,%rdx`

Comment: To solve this yourself with gdb, you should always print out the address that faulted.  Since the addressing mode was `(%rdx)`, run `p /x $rdx`.  You would have seen hex digits that were suspiciously in the ASCII range.  e.g. `0x000000FF??????`, where the ?? bytes are the hex values of the ASCII encoding of `-149`.  That would be a big clue that you didn't have an address in `%rdx`, especially after printing `S` and seeing that its address was `0x4...` or something (data-section addresses on Linux are in the low 2G of address space, so a sign-extended 32bit displacement can address them.)

Comment: I set a break on line 10 to print S but GDB said `$1 = Value can't be converted to integer.`

since Its a string, this makes sense. 

Putting S into %rdx gave me `(gdb) p /x $rdx
$3 = 0x601038` 

Which doesn't make sense to me value wise. Whats going on here?

Comment: Line 10 is the `mov     S,%rdx`.  If you break there, `%rdx` hasn't been written yet.  I just checked a simple example:  A .data section address in my test case was `0x600464`, as printed by `p /x &something`.  Note the `&` to get the address, not the contents.  A .rodata section address happened to be `0x400424`  (read-only data goes in the `.text` section after linking).  So `0x601038` looks like a normal data-section address to me.  If your code still had the bug (`mov S, %rdx` instead of `mov $S, %rdx`), you'd have seen something totally different in %rdx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
mov $S,%edx
```

to load the address of the string into `%rdx`. This works because the program image is always loaded into the lower 4 GB of the address space. Alternatively, you can use a `%rip` relative `lea` to load the address even if the process image is loaded outside of the first 4 GB:

```
lea S(%rip),%rdx
```

but that instruction has a somewhat longer encoding (two extra bytes).

The instruction

```
mov S,%rdx
```

loads the first eight bytes of the memory `S` points to into `%rdx`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Im trying to keep everything the same size as further down the code I was getting size mismatch for imul. 

    mov $S, %rdx

Would this be sufficient?

Comment: Similarly line 28 is giving me a segfault as well.

Comment: @Egyptian_Coder `mov $S, %rdx` does the same thing as `mov $S,%edx` but consumes an extra byte of storage. If you load something into a 32 bit register, the high 32 bit of the register are automatically zeroes out. In line 28, `length` occupies one byte of storage but your `cmp` tries to read eight bytes. What do you think happens?